# How to duplicate UILabel Style on Swift 3 programatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel

I've created a UILabel through storyboard, but now I want to create another one programatically with the same properties of the first one

How can I duplicate or create a UILabel using the same style (font color, background, size, center, bold...) from other existing UILabel programatically.

Comment: Cmd+c, Cmd+v ... also you can create your own custom class and subclass from UILabel

Answer (score 2):

You can create extension on `UILabel` and add a method to style label.

```
extension UILabel {
    func applyStyle() {
        self.textColor = .black
        self.textAlignment = .center
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)
    }
}
```

now you call `myLabel.applyStyle()` to use same properties for different labels

Comment: It's a good idea but I need to "copy" the entire style from another existing UILabel.

Comment: you can keep all the style and configuration part in this extension method and call applyStyle from all the labels where you want to apply this style.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom subclass of UILabel which has the properties you want it to have and then when you create you label just set its class to the custom class.

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
   required init?(code aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(code: aDecoder)
      //your code goes here
      self.textColor = UIColor.red
      self.alpha = 0.5
   }
}
```

So just add to your project a swift file and add the code above to it. There you can just add your properties.

I hope this helped